# How to change the default shell in iTerm?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, zsh, iterm

I'm having some difficulties in changing the value of `$SHELL` in OSX's iTerm app. iTerm is starting in `/bin/zsh`, but the value of `$SHELL` doesn't seem to change.

#### What I've done:

1. Changed "command" as `/bin/zsh` in iTerm's configuration window.
2. Executed `chsh` to change the shell to `/bin/zsh`.
3. Confirmed iTerm is started in `/bin/zsh`

#### NOTE #1: In OSX's stock terminal app, "Terminal.app":

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

#### NOTE #2: In OSX's popular terminal app, "iTerm.app":

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ echo $USER
$ melvkim

$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for melvkim.
Password for melvkim:
chsh: no changes made
```

Comment: Have you looked in `/etc/shells` ? The manual states that if the shell you specify is not in that file, it isn't considered a standard shell.

Comment: You real problem isn’t to change the $SHELL, but your real default shell in `iTerm`. The variable is built at login shell from the default shell used by `iTerm`.

Comment: could you mark your answer as correct to mark the question as answered? You can mark your own answer as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The problem was the "iTerm" app's conflicting settings with the shell. To resolve, I've reset "login shell" command in iTerm preference window:

> iTerm.app -> Preferences -> Profiles -> General -> Command -> Click on "Login shell"

Then, I executed `chsh` to modify it as `/bin/zsh`.

To reproduce the problem (having $SHELL set as `/bin/bash/`, even though the login shell is `/bin/zsh`), I just had to change "iTerm" setting back to "Command: /bin/zsh/".

Comment: Buddy of mine had the same issue w/ intelliJ.

Comment: re: "iTerm.app -> Preferences". I'm a long time Linux user (hence why I'm here) but new to iOs. I just can't find this instruction. More guidance would be appreciated. I really want bash in IOs!

Comment: @StephenHosking with iTerm active, do `CMD + ,` to reach Preferences

Comment: Remove the `/` at the end of your `iTerm` preferences shell path, because it might cause errors in shell scripts.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue but I **resolved it** by executing the command `chsh -s /bin/zsh` in the terminal,then navigated to

> Terminal -> Preferences -> General window

and changed the *Shells open with:* option to *Default login shell* while the *command (complete path)* set to */bin/zsh*.This should solve your problem.

Comment: This was my issue and this resolved it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23072501/997225) for the excellent explanation and solution posted by @mklement0 [in relation to a `bash` upgrade problem.

I had a similar problem in doing the opposite on my system (OS X 10.10.1): making `bash` the default login shell again after I had installed [`oh-my-zsh`](http://ohmyz.sh/), which made `zsh` the default, and then upgrading `bash` from 3.2.53 to 4.3.30 using Homebrew (why is Apple shipping Yosemite with an old `bash` version?).

I think the `SHELL` environment variable reflects but does *not* control the actual default login shell for the user.  For example, if, say, `bash` was your default and you open a new `bash` shell window from terminal then `$ export SHELL="/bin/zsh"; echo "$SHELL"` would show `/bin/zsh` but no actual change will occur because if you open a new shell window from terminal and do `$ echo $0` then you would see `-bash` (`$0` contains the name and path of the command that started the shell window, in this case `bash`, and the `-` next to it indicates that it is a login shell).

As @mklement0 pointed out the actual default login shell for the user is controlled by the `UserShell` property in the user's record in the system's internal database - this can be queried and updated using the command line utility [`dscl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html).  This information will passed to your terminal app when you open a shell window.

What `chsh -s /bin/zsh` does is change this `UserShell` property to set it to `zsh` - you can check this by doing `dscl . -read /Users/$USER/ UserShell` immediately afterwards, and you will see `UserShell: /bin/zsh`.  But the change is *not* effected in the current window, until you do something like `exec su - $USER` as suggested by @mklement0, or until you close and open a shell window.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the command: `chsh -s /bin/zsh` from the default Mac terminal.

Comment: What does this do differently from the OP?

Comment: @JMY1000 If you try to execute that command from iTerm, the changes aren't reflected. You should be able to get it working by executing it from Mac's default terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The `-s` flag for `chsh` only attempts to change the shell, and probably fails due to Open Directory:  The usual UNIX system 'chsh' would modify the `/etc/passwd` entry.   However, I was able to run `chsh` with no arguments, which gave me an editor, and the following information:

```
# Changing user information for nevin.
# Use "passwd" to change the password.
##
# Open Directory: /Local/Default
##
Shell: /bin/tcsh
Full Name: Nevin Williams
Office Location:
Office Phone:
Home Phone:
```

I was able to edit the "Shell:" entry to `/bin/zsh`, and subsequent Terminal windows opened with a Z-shell prompt.

Comment: I tried `chsh` with no args. Still no luck. The variable doesn't change. In fact, when the editor was loaded, it showed `/bin/zsh`.

Comment: Try changing the shell with the editor.   I made a screen capture of me changing from /bin/tcsh to /bin/zsh and back.  http://bonmot.ca/~nevin/chsh.mov

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time recording posting your screencast! Your solution is supposed to be working on other terminal emulators, but I wasn't abel to change `$SHELL` on iTerm. Please refer to my answer for details.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  The Terminal would open into bash.  csh -s /bin/zsh would fail with an error.  Examining the default shell in System Preferences->Users by control-clicking on my user showed /bin/zsh was set.  dscl showed /bin/zsh was set.  I tried resetting Terminal->Preferences to /bin/zsh.  That also failed.

Ultimately, it turned out there was a lockfile.  Going to ~/Library/Preferences, I deleted com.apple.Terminal.plist.lockfile and com.apple.Terminal.plist.  That fixed the problem.  On the next startup, zsh loaded correctly in the terminal.